# Cannot find Chrome_OmniboxView

Tags: c++

I cannot find Chrome_OmniboxView. I think the name of Chrome maybe change. The code as following cannot work anymore.
Please help me.

```
hwndChromeMain = FindMainWebBroswer(L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1"); // OK
// get buffer
::SendMessage(hwndChromeMain, WM_GETTEXT, 255, (LPARAM)buffer);  // OK        
// saved buffer
// find chrome child tab
hwndChromeChild = ::FindWindowExW(hwndChromeMain, NULL, L"Chrome_OmniboxView", NULL); // NOT OK
```

The hwndChromeChild is always NULL.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer possible as of Chrome version 28, as the Omnibox no longer has a HWND.

You will need to change the way you are interacting with the Omnibox. One way would be to use the Microsoft Automation Framework.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246644